# IONIC 3 cordova run android not working after adding googlemaps plugin

Tags: cordova, google-maps, ionic3

After adding the googlemaps plugin to my project, I can no longer deploy my Ionic application on my laptop. I have been looking for solutions on the internet for 2 days already but I have no conclusive results. It shows me errors that are not related to my code. What can I do? Would anyone have a solution track?
Cordova 7.01
Ionic 3.10.3
Here's my log

```
    xecution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MapStyleOptions;
                                        ^
  symbol:   class MapStyleOptions
  location: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
    GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener, GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveCanceledListener,
             ^
  symbol:   class OnCameraIdleListener
  location: class GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
    GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener, GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveCanceledListener,
                                             ^
  symbol:   class OnCameraMoveCanceledListener
  location: class GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
    GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener, GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener,
             ^
  symbol:   class OnCameraMoveListener
  location: class GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
    GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener, GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener,
                                             ^
  symbol:   class OnCameraMoveStartedListener
  location: class GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
    GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowLongClickListener, GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowCloseListener {
             ^
  symbol:   class OnInfoWindowLongClickListener
  location: class GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
    GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowLongClickListener, GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowCloseListener {
                                                      ^
  symbol:   class OnInfoWindowCloseListener
  location: class GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:242: error: cannot find symbol
                MapStyleOptions styleOptions = new MapStyleOptions(styles);
                ^
  symbol: class MapStyleOptions
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:242: error: cannot find symbol
                MapStyleOptions styleOptions = new MapStyleOptions(styles);
                                                   ^
  symbol: class MapStyleOptions
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:282: error: cannot find symbol
                    map.setMinZoomPreference((float)zoom.getDouble("minZoom"));
                       ^
  symbol:   method setMinZoomPreference(float)
  location: variable map of type GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:285: error: cannot find symbol
                    map.setMaxZoomPreference((float)zoom.getDouble("maxZoom"));
                       ^
  symbol:   method setMaxZoomPreference(float)
  location: variable map of type GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:291: error: cannot find symbol
              map.setOnCameraIdleListener(PluginMap.this);
                 ^
  symbol:   method setOnCameraIdleListener(PluginMap)
  location: variable map of type GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:292: error: cannot find symbol
              map.setOnCameraMoveCanceledListener(PluginMap.this);
                 ^
  symbol:   method setOnCameraMoveCanceledListener(PluginMap)
  location: variable map of type GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:293: error: cannot find symbol
              map.setOnCameraMoveListener(PluginMap.this);
                 ^
  symbol:   method setOnCameraMoveListener(PluginMap)
  location: variable map of type GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:294: error: cannot find symbol
              map.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(PluginMap.this);
                 ^
  symbol:   method setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(PluginMap)
  location: variable map of type GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:303: error: cannot find symbol
              map.setOnInfoWindowLongClickListener(PluginMap.this);
                 ^
  symbol:   method setOnInfoWindowLongClickListener(PluginMap)
  location: variable map of type GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:304: error: cannot find symbol
              map.setOnInfoWindowCloseListener(PluginMap.this);
                 ^
  symbol:   method setOnInfoWindowCloseListener(PluginMap)
  location: variable map of type GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:347: error: cannot find symbol
                      map.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
                                                               ^
  symbol:   class OnCameraIdleListener
  location: class GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:366: error: cannot find symbol
                  map.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
                                                           ^
  symbol:   class OnCameraIdleListener
  location: class GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:652: error: cannot find symbol
                  map.setOnPolylineClickListener(null);
                     ^
  symbol:   method setOnPolylineClickListener(<null>)
  location: variable map of type GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:653: error: cannot find symbol
                  map.setOnPolygonClickListener(null);
                     ^
  symbol:   method setOnPolygonClickListener(<null>)
  location: variable map of type GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:655: error: cannot find symbol
                  map.setOnCircleClickListener(null);
                     ^
  symbol:   method setOnCircleClickListener(<null>)
  location: variable map of type GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:656: error: cannot find symbol
                  map.setOnGroundOverlayClickListener(null);
                     ^
  symbol:   method setOnGroundOverlayClickListener(<null>)
  location: variable map of type GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:657: error: cannot find symbol
                  map.setOnCameraIdleListener(null);
                     ^
  symbol:   method setOnCameraIdleListener(<null>)
  location: variable map of type GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:658: error: cannot find symbol
                  map.setOnCameraMoveCanceledListener(null);
                     ^
  symbol:   method setOnCameraMoveCanceledListener(<null>)
  location: variable map of type GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:659: error: cannot find symbol
                  map.setOnCameraMoveListener(null);
                     ^
  symbol:   method setOnCameraMoveListener(<null>)
  location: variable map of type GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:661: error: cannot find symbol
                  map.setOnInfoWindowCloseListener(null);
                     ^
  symbol:   method setOnInfoWindowCloseListener(<null>)
  location: variable map of type GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:734: error: cannot find symbol
    String markerTag = (String) marker.getTag();
                                      ^
  symbol:   method getTag()
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:764: error: cannot find symbol
    if ((marker.getTag() + "").startsWith("markercluster_")){
               ^
  symbol:   method getTag()
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:952: error: cannot find symbol
    String markerTag = (String) marker.getTag();
                                      ^
  symbol:   method getTag()
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:976: error: cannot find symbol
          if ((marker.getTag() + "").startsWith("markercluster_")){
                     ^
  symbol:   method getTag()
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:1104: error: cannot find symbol
          MapStyleOptions styleOptions = new MapStyleOptions(results.styles);
          ^
  symbol: class MapStyleOptions
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:1104: error: cannot find symbol
          MapStyleOptions styleOptions = new MapStyleOptions(results.styles);
                                             ^
  symbol: class MapStyleOptions
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:1142: error: cannot find symbol
                map.setMinZoomPreference((float)zoom.getDouble("minZoom"));
                   ^
  symbol:   method setMinZoomPreference(float)
  location: variable map of type GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:1145: error: cannot find symbol
                map.setMaxZoomPreference((float)zoom.getDouble("maxZoom"));
                   ^
  symbol:   method setMaxZoomPreference(float)
  location: variable map of type GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:1446: error: cannot find symbol
                  map.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
                                                           ^
  symbol:   class OnCameraIdleListener
  location: class GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:1482: error: cannot find symbol
                  map.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
                                                           ^
  symbol:   class OnCameraIdleListener
  location: class GoogleMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:1992: error: cannot find symbol
    String clusterId_markerId = marker.getTag() + "";
                                      ^
  symbol:   method getTag()
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:2047: error: cannot find symbol
    String markerTag = marker.getTag() + "";
                             ^
  symbol:   method getTag()
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:2060: error: cannot find symbol
    if ((marker.getTag() + "").startsWith("markercluster_")){
               ^
  symbol:   method getTag()
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:2072: error: cannot find symbol
    if ((marker.getTag() + "").startsWith("markercluster_")){
               ^
  symbol:   method getTag()
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:2084: error: cannot find symbol
    if ((marker.getTag() + "").startsWith("markercluster_")){
               ^
  symbol:   method getTag()
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:2091: error: method does not override or implement a method from a sup
ertype
  @Override
  ^
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:2095: error: cannot find symbol
    if ((marker.getTag() + "").startsWith("markercluster_")){
               ^
  symbol:   method getTag()
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:2102: error: method does not override or implement a method from a sup
ertype
  @Override
  ^
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:2107: error: cannot find symbol
      String markerTag = marker.getTag() + "";
                               ^
  symbol:   method getTag()
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:2136: error: cannot find symbol
    if (marker.getTag() == null) {
              ^
  symbol:   method getTag()
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:2141: error: cannot find symbol
    String markerTag = (String) marker.getTag();
                                      ^
  symbol:   method getTag()
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:2150: error: cannot find symbol
    if (marker.getTag() == null) {
              ^
  symbol:   method getTag()
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:2155: error: cannot find symbol
    String markerTag = (String) marker.getTag();
                                      ^
  symbol:   method getTag()
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:2446: error: method does not override or implement a method from a sup
ertype
  @Override
  ^
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:2456: error: method does not override or implement a method from a sup
ertype
  @Override
  ^
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:2466: error: method does not override or implement a method from a sup
ertype
  @Override
  ^
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:2475: error: method does not override or implement a method from a sup
ertype
  @Override
  ^
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:2481: error: cannot find symbol
    this.isDragging = reason == REASON_GESTURE;
                                ^
  symbol:   variable REASON_GESTURE
  location: class PluginMap
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:2597: error: cannot find symbol
              String markerTag = activeMarker.getTag() + "";
                                             ^
  symbol:   method getTag()
  location: variable activeMarker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginCircle.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
    circleOptions.clickable(false);
                 ^
  symbol:   method clickable(boolean)
  location: variable circleOptions of type CircleOptions
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginGroundOverlay.java:91: error: cannot find symbol
    options.clickable(false);
           ^
  symbol:   method clickable(boolean)
  location: variable options of type GroundOverlayOptions
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginGroundOverlay.java:161: error: cannot find symbol
                  groundOverlay.setTag(null);
                               ^
  symbol:   method setTag(<null>)
  location: variable groundOverlay of type GroundOverlay
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMarker.java:157: error: cannot find symbol
                marker.setTag(null);
                      ^
  symbol:   method setTag(<null>)
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMarker.java:249: error: cannot find symbol
      markerOptions.zIndex((float) opts.getDouble("zIndex"));
                   ^
  symbol:   method zIndex(float)
  location: variable markerOptions of type MarkerOptions
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMarker.java:275: error: cannot find symbol
        marker.setTag(markerId);
              ^
  symbol:   method setTag(String)
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMarker.java:810: error: cannot find symbol
    if (marker == null || marker.getTag() == null) {
                                ^
  symbol:   method getTag()
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMarker.java:817: error: cannot find symbol
    String iconCacheKey = "marker_icon_" + marker.getTag();
                                                 ^
  symbol:   method getTag()
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMarker.java:818: error: cannot find symbol
    marker.setTag(null);
          ^
  symbol:   method setTag(<null>)
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMarker.java:1010: error: cannot find symbol
          String markerTag = marker.getTag() + "";
                                   ^
  symbol:   method getTag()
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMarker.java:1043: error: cannot find symbol
            if (marker == null || marker.getTag() == null) {
                                        ^
  symbol:   method getTag()
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMarker.java:1065: error: cannot find symbol
          if (bitmapDescriptor == null || marker == null || marker.getTag() == null) {
                                                                  ^
  symbol:   method getTag()
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMarkerCluster.java:451: error: cannot find symbol
            marker.setTag(clusterId_markerId);
                  ^
  symbol:   method setTag(String)
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginMarkerCluster.java:626: error: cannot find symbol
          if (marker != null && marker.getTag() != null) {
                                      ^
  symbol:   method getTag()
  location: variable marker of type Marker
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginPolygon.java:105: error: cannot find symbol
        polygonOptions.clickable(false);
                      ^
  symbol:   method clickable(boolean)
  location: variable polygonOptions of type PolygonOptions
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginPolyline.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
    polylineOptions.clickable(false);
                   ^
  symbol:   method clickable(boolean)
  location: variable polylineOptions of type PolylineOptions
C:\Users\Herve\IONIC\toplivreur\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginTileOverlay.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
      options.transparency((float)(1 - opts.getDouble("opacity")));
             ^
  symbol:   method transparency(float)
  location: variable options of type TileOverlayOptions
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
73 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Here is my package.json content

```
{
    "name": "app_name",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
        "@ionic-native/base64-to-gallery": "^4.2.1",
        "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.2.1",
        "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/file": "^4.2.1",
        "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.2.1",
        "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^4.2.1",
        "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^4.2.1",
        "@ionic-native/secure-storage": "^4.2.1",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^4.2.1",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^0.1.0",
        "ajv": "^5.0.0",
        "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
        "cordova-base64-to-gallery": "^4.1.2",
        "cordova-browser": "^4.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "^2.4.1",
        "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "^4.3.3",
        "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^2.4.3",
        "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.2.2",
        "cordova-plugin-secure-storage": "^2.6.8",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.0.4",
        "ionic-angular": "3.6.1",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "jssha": "^2.3.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "rxjs": "5.4.0",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.12"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.4",
        "@types/lodash": "4.14.74",
        "typescript": "2.3.4"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-console": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-base64-to-gallery": {},
            "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
            "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {},
            "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file": {},
            "cordova-plugin-secure-storage": {},
            "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "android",
            "browser"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try after deleting the `node_module` folder?

Comment: can you include package.json in your question?

Comment: Sorry I'm late! Yes I've tried deleting all and "npm install" again but got the same error.